# error while using @Valid in spring mvc 3.0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, validation, spring-mvc

here what i do in a model class

```
private Integer height;

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 2, max = 3)
public Integer getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(Integer height) {
    this.height = height;
}
```

but there is a validation error in the jsp page while running, it says that cannot validate the integer value.

in the message.properties file

> NotBlank.modelClassName.height=Required in cm.
>   Length.modelClassName.height=min {0} max (1).
>   typeMismatch.modelClassName.height=numbers only.

help me please

Comment: what exactly does it say? what's the message? Is there any stacktrace. Which version of hibernate validator (or which jsr 303 provider) ?

Comment: ok tell me how i validate an integer value in spring which is inputted from jsp page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both annotations [@NotBlank](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) and [@Length](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Length.html) must be applied to an String attribute not to an Integer one, as it is stated in the links. Maybe you can use [@NotNull](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/NotNull.html), [@Min](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Min.html) or [@Max](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Max.html) that could be used for numbers.